# Flex/as3: If I set BorderContainer's BorderWeight, contained Label is shifted...why?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, label, border-container

I have a BorderContainer with a Label inside. I need this Label to be centered inside the container. BorderContainer has no layout (I guess it getst the default one, basicLayout...).

My code:

BorderContainer's definition:

```
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="bordercontainer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                addedToStage="bordercontainer1_addedToStageHandler(event)"
               cornerRadius="200" borderWeight="20"  >
```

When my BorderContainer is completed, I load dynamically the Label:

```
protected function bordercontainer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var countdownText:Label = new Label();
                countdownText.width = this.width * 0.5;
                //countdownText.height = this.height * 0.5;
                countdownText.text =String( countdownDuration );
                    countdownText.setStyle("fontSize","200");
                    countdownText.setStyle("fontFamily", "Arial");
                    countdownText.setStyle("color","#FF0000");
                    countdownText.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold" );
                    countdownText.setStyle("textAlign", "center");                  
                this.addElement(countdownText);
                //trace("width border:", this.width, ", text width:", countdownText.width);
                countdownText.x = (this.width-countdownText.width)/2;
                countdownText.y = (this.width-countdownText.width)/2;

        }
```

With this code the Label's text is centered in the container, but if I set the BorderWeight property, the text is shifted!!!!!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why are you adding this text dynamically like that?  Is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I am not sure what you mean by "shifted".  I was not able to reproduce the problem with your code... though your code is incomplete.  What is `countdownText` or `bordercontainer1_addedToStageHandler`, for instance?

How about avoiding the dynamic code and just use a simple data binding?

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Number id="countdownDuration">5.123</fx:Number>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:BorderContainer cornerRadius="200" borderWeight="20" width="100%" height="100%">

    <mx:Label width="50%" text="{countdownDuration}"
             fontSize="200" fontFamily="Arial" color="#FF0000"
             fontWeight="bold" textAlign="center"
             verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />

</s:BorderContainer>
```